Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
I got this error: Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection when I'm executing the following code:
withr::with_dir(here::here(), {
targets::tar_load(all_zipped_projects)
targets::tar_load(all_slides)

I do not know whether is a matter of being located in an specific working directory or what.

First of all, what language is that code written in? Please [edit] your question to add it as a tag. Secondly, please try to create a [mre] to show us, where the "input" is hard-coded.
